# jasper report - how to add asterisk to barcode numeric output?

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, ireport, barcode4j

I'm created `jrxml` using `iReport` and generating barcode using `barcode4j`.

**Goal:**

Output barcode with numeric value which has **asterisks**.

Looks something like below.

```
||||||||||
*123456*
```

**barcode section of jrxml:**

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement x="29" y="4" width="209" height="32"/>
    <jr:Code39 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" textPosition="bottom">
        <jr:codeExpression>
            <![CDATA["*" + $P{barCode} + "*"]]>
        </jr:codeExpression>
    </jr:Code39>
</componentElement>
```

The code above runs fine except the output barcode does not have asterisk.

So it looks like:

```
|||||||||
123456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### See **UPDATE** section for valid answer.

The trick was to set **extendedCharSetEnabled attribute to true.**

I got the idea from following sites:

http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/components.schema.reference.html#_extendedCharSetEnabled

http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/symbol-code39.html

So the whole barcode xml part looks like this:

```
<componentElement>
   <reportElement x="29" y="4" width="209" height="32"/>
   <jr:Code39 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" 
textPosition="bottom"
extendedCharSetEnabled="true">

       <jr:codeExpression>
           <![CDATA["*" + $P{barCode} + "*"]]>
       </jr:codeExpression>
   </jr:Code39>
</componentElement>
```

**UPDATE:**

Due to the solution above would output barcode which contains asterisks when scanned.

The true solution is to use **displayStartStop attribute and set it to true**.
And remove asterisk concatenation from CDATA area.

```
<componentElement>
       <reportElement x="29" y="4" width="209" height="32"/>
       <jr:Code39 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" 
    textPosition="bottom"
    displayStartStop="true">

           <jr:codeExpression>
               <![CDATA[$P{barCode}]]>
           </jr:codeExpression>
       </jr:Code39>
    </componentElement>
```

NOTE:

Don't use extendedCharSetEnabled attribute together with displayStartStop as asterisks won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  <![CDATA["*" + $P{barCode} + "*"]]>
```

try using

```
  <![CDATA['*'+$P{barCode}+'*']]>
```